# Executing two similar Jenkinsfile pipelines without duplicating code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins with a declarative pipeline for continuously testing one of my Python projects. I would like to generalize my `Jenkinsfile` to test my project with several Python versions, possibly in parallel. Let's say my current `Jenkinsfile` looks like this:

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      dir("src") {
        steps {
          checkout scm
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Install') {
      sh """
      python3.4 -m venv virtualenv
      source virtualenv/bin/activate
      python3.4 -m pip install src
      """
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to parametrize the generation of the pipeline by moving it to a function, as follows:

```
def generatePipeline(version) {
  pipeline {
    stages {
      stage('Checkout') {
        dir("src") {
          steps {
            checkout scm
          }
        }
      }
      stage('Install') {
        sh """
        python${version} -m venv virtualenv
        source virtualenv/bin/activate
        python${version} -m pip install src
        """
      }
    }
  }
}

generatePipeline("3.4")
```

Jenkins fails with the message `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'stages' found among steps` *(huge list follows)*.

I have unsuccessfully cargo-culted countless other things (including putting `generatePipeline` in a shared library), but I don't really understand how declarative pipelines (or even Groovy) work. Is there a way to generate several similar pipelines without duplicating all the common code?

Comment: You want this: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks, I have tried that, but I have failed to make it work. Can you please expand a bit on the steps to take? For example, do I need to store the shared library in a separate SCM repository, or can I put it in the same repository as my ``Jenkinsfile`` (which I would prefer)? Do I need to mark it as trusted if it sits in the same repo? And, most importantly, what should the function in my shared library return? A pipeline, a collection of stages, something else entirely...?

Answer (score 2):

You must pass the pipeline script context into your method and call pipline from that.

```
    def generatePipeline(version, context) {
        context.pipeline {
            stages {
                //...
            }
        }
    }

    generatePipeline("3.4", this)
```

Comment: Jenkins complains with ``java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'stages' found among steps [...]``.
Edit: the message terminates with ``...] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]``. I see ``pipeline`` there, which perhaps explains why Jenkins did not complain about it even without ``context``.

Comment: I think, the problem here is, that you try to use declarative pipeline syntax, which doesn't allow that flexible Groovy syntax. Have a look into [scripted pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline).